# Convert string to datetime MVC4

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

The question looks little obvious but I hardly found suggestions on this.

I have a date and time as string like below:

```
string s = "Fri Jun 28 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
DateTime from = Convert.ToDateTime(s).ToUniversalTime();
```

But this throws the exception:

```
{System.SystemException}: {"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}
```

Can somebody advise how can I handle this?

Comment: _"I hardly found suggestions on this."_ - I find that hard to believe. Please show the code where you perform the conversion.

Comment: string s = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("FromDate").AttemptedValue;

            DateTime from = Convert.ToDateTime(s).ToUniversalTime();

Comment: strange that u down voted? my string is different here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) method:

```
string s = "Fri Jun 28 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz '(India Standard Time)'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    // You could use the date here
}
else
{
    // The string was not in the correct format
}
```

Comment: Everything that is enclosed in simple quotes is interpreted as a literal string. So in this case `'GMT'` is a literal whereas `zzz` is the timezone specifier in a [`datetime format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).